# How do you keep your jQuery plugins updated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm guessing I'll have to go to each plugin's site and subscribe to the site's RSS feed...but I thought I'd ask, just in case there's a better way.

This is assuming that I even want to keep the plugins updated...Hey if it's working...why change it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, I don't. If I use a plugin, and it's working as exptected...it doesn't need updated.

No need to do extra work and risk breaking something if you have it working already.

Comment: +1 Indeed. Any changes to that plugin would be undesirable because they could alter my app's behavior.

Comment: +1, though I do check the changelog before the testing begins for a decent release (2-4x a year) to see if any bugfixes have come up that will impact me

Comment: +1 from me too.  However the main down-side to this philosophy is when new browser versions are released and suddenly your outdated jQuery and plugins are broken anyway... you can't win.  We just went through this with IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding that there are NuGet packages for many of the commonly used jQuery plugins and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think that it's a good idea to use plug-ins and never do an update.**

For example:

You are using jQuery and a few plug-ins that seem to work all right for this version, you're pleased with the result and decide to stop following the new updates on the used plug-ins.

jQuery does some updates on and after 2 updates you realize that your plug-in stopped working.
Ok, you might want to do an update on this plug-in. But it's possible that it stopped working a few weeks before you noticed the errors... I'll bet your visitors aren't very pleased with the malfunctioning website.

Ok, off course there is a smart ass who says that if you don't update your jQuery, your plug-ins will always work. True but the problem there is that jQuery will stop supporting older versions after a while. So i do believe that you try to stay updated on your plug-ins.

*What is the best way to do that?*

I guess rss, twitter and all those communities keep you up to date in a sufficient way.
If not, I just guess you are trying to use to much plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I ussualy update plugins following this checklist:

- Is a critical update?

  - No - Leave it until next site update iteration.
  - Yes - Does it changes functionality?

    - No - Update to latest version.
    - Yes - Prepare for a lot of work and little sleep to rush a site update.
    - For both - Test the hell out of it!

At every site version iteration, I try to keep with the latest stable version of the plugins.
If it's an "unstable" (no formal release), I fork to my own server, and merge regularly.

---

One thing, iterations in this context could mean anything *to you*. You could consither them to range from a few days/a week to a few months/a year. I'd advice to make faster iterations.